# Is my binary search algorithm (a) correct and (b) efficient?

Tags: algorithm, search, dart, binary-search

I have written a simple method for adding in new elements to a sorted list class, the code is in Dart but should be fairly obvious what is going on in all C like languages, I have run a couple of simple unit tests on it and it does seem to add in new elements in the correct order, my questions are, is it full proof? and could it be more efficient? I'm trying to use a binary search to find an appropriate index to insert at, also it returns the index the new object was inserted to:

```
int add(T obj){

  int loIdx = 0;
  int upIdx = list.length - 1;
  int i;

  while(loIdx <= upIdx){

    i = loIdx + ((upIdx - loIdx) >> 1);

    switch(_compare(obj, list[i])){

      case 0:

        loIdx = i;

        upIdx = i - 1;

        break;

      case -1:

        upIdx = i - 1;

        if(loIdx == upIdx){

          if(_compare(obj, list[loIdx]) == 1){

            loIdx++;

          }

        }

        break;

      case 1:

        loIdx = i + 1;

        break;

    }

  }

  list.insert(loIdx, obj);

  return loIdx;

}
```

Just for completeness, here is one of the unit tests Im using to show it does actually work:

```
test('Order',(){

  SortedList<int> intList = new SortedList<int>((int a, int b) => a.compareTo(b));

  intList.add(5);
  intList.add(7);
  intList.add(0);
  intList.add(3);
  intList.add(6);
  intList.add(9);
  intList.add(1);
  intList.add(2);
  intList.add(8);
  intList.add(5);
  intList.add(4);

  expect(intList.list, orderedEquals([0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9]));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Dart, but the line:

```
i = loIdx + ((upIdx - loIdx) % 2);
```

looks really odd.  Normally I would expect to see something like:

```
i = loIdx + ((upIdx - loIdx) >> 1);
```

or

```
i = loIdx + ((upIdx - loIdx) / 2);
```

Comment: @MarioP : i think Peter is right : what you search is the middle index, so you should use integer divide by two (~/2) or, faster, shift (>>1). As of now your algorithm move only one (or even 0) index further each time, so it is O(n^2), not O(ln(n)). Also, take care of overhead : for small list (say <5 or even more ) indexOf or a  well written manual search will be faster.

Comment: @GameAlchemist sorry, i didn't really look at the code itself - the wording made me think it is syntactically odd. I should probably read more carefully.

Comment: I though x % 2 was x >> 1, Yikes! that's bad, I can't believe it even works at all in that case. thanks I forgot that modulo returns the remainder not the value of integer division.